# Split urls/text by spaces into 2 boxes Javascript Only no libraries

Tags: javascript

Well so far i havent been able to get it to change the input box value.
What i want it to do?
I want it to take the text from the first box. And when you click the button splits it and appends them to the 2nd and 3rd box.

I don't want to use jquery or any libraries purely javascript.

Any questions ask away.

Not sure what im doing wrong here. Seems it should work. Any help? Thanks
Edited this is working for what i need.... not sure if its the best way but it does work
Code

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD> 
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        var urls_1;
        var split_text;
    function addto_boxes(form) {
            var split_text = document.getElementById("text_to_split").value;
            var urls_1 = split_text.split(" ", 100000);
            document.getElementById("input_box1").value = document.getElementById("input_box1").value + urls_1[0] + " ";
            document.getElementById("input_box2").value = document.getElementById("input_box2").value + urls_1[1] + " ";
    }


    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <input id="Split" type="button" value="Add to boxes" onclick="addto_boxes(this.form);"/><Br>
    <textarea NAME="texttosplit" id="text_to_split" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75"></textarea><Br>


    <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Put 1st urls in this box:
    <textarea NAME="inputbox" id="input_box1" VALUE=""rows="4" cols="75"></textarea><Br>
    Put 2nd urls in this box: <Br>
    <textarea NAME="inputbox2" id="input_box2" VALUE=""rows="4" cols="75"></textarea><Br>
    <INPUT TYPE="reset">
    </FORM>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Well it was correct in that it does add the text to the boxes. the answer that was posted. But how do i get it to add them again or new text when the button is clicked? Without overwirtting text already in the box.

Comment: Aha, addition to the original question. Add them how, what should the output format look like? Comma separated?

Comment: Well with the + " " space delimited. thought that was clear? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

HTML

```
<input id="Split" type="button" value="Add to boxes" />
<Br>
<textarea NAME="texttosplit" id="text_to_split" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75"></textarea>
<Br>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Put 1st urls in this box:
    <textarea NAME="inputbox" id="input_box1" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75"></textarea>
    <Br>Put 2nd urls in this box:
    <Br>
    <textarea NAME="inputbox2" id="input_box2" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75"></textarea>
    <Br>
    <INPUT id="reset" TYPE="reset">
</FORM>
```

Javascript

```
var aBox1 = [];
var aBox2 = [];

document.getElementById("Split").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var urls_1 = document.getElementById("text_to_split").value.trim().split(" "),
        url1 = urls_1[0] || "",
        url2 = urls_1[1] || "";

    if (url1.length) {
        aBox1.push(url1);
    }

    if (url2.length) {
        aBox2.push(url2);
    }

    document.getElementById("input_box1").value = aBox1.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("input_box2").value = aBox2.join(" ");
}, false);

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function () {
    aBox1.length = 0;
    aBox2.length = 0;
}, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ewpMR/)

Comment: I figure it out...   document.getElementById("input_box1").value = document.getElementById("input_box1").value + urls_1[0] + " "; works to fo what i need it to.

Comment: Also it doesnt append the data to the boxes. as stated origonally. i needed the values already in the box to stay there and the text be added to the end. i edited my question with the working solution i found.