# Javascript (no libraries) split text to populate textboxes with different text

Tags: javascript

Related to [Split urls/text by spaces into 2 boxes Javascript Only no libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289107/split-urls-text-by-spaces-into-2-boxes-javascript-only-no-libraries)

What I want to do is split text, which is already in the textbox. I want it to be put into a variable. Then, because there are 2 boxes, I want the first one filled with 1 2 3 4 5. The second box filled with 6 7 8 9 10. Or the first box with 1 3 5 7 9 and the second one with 2 4 6 8 10. Whichever way works best/easiest.

This is what I have tried so far.

Code:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      var split_text;
      var urls_1;
      var numbercount=0;
      var totals;
      var half_totals;
      function addto_boxes(form) {
        split_text = document.getElementById("text_to_split").value;
        urls_1 = split_text.split(" ", 100000);
        totals = urls_1.lenght - 1;
        half_totals = (totals / 2 );
        while (numbercount <= half_totals ){
          if (numbercount >= half_totals ){
            numbercount = 0;
            break;
          document.getElementById("input_box1").value = document.getElementById("input_box1").value + urls_1[numbercount] + " ";
          document.getElementById("input_box2").value = document.getElementById("input_box2").value + urls_1[numbercount + half_totals] + " ";
          numbercount++
        }
      }
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <input id="Split" type="button" value="Add to boxes" onclick="addto_boxes(this.form);"/>
    <BR>
    <textarea NAME="texttosplit" id="text_to_split" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </textarea>
    <BR>
    <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Put 1st urls in this box (Separated by a space):
      <textarea NAME="inputbox" id="input_box1" VALUE=""rows="4" cols="75"></textarea>
      <BR>
      Put 2nd urls in this box <BR>
      <textarea NAME="inputbox2" id="input_box2" VALUE=""rows="4" cols="75"></textarea>
      <BR>
      <INPUT TYPE="reset">
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You have a spelling error: `totals = urls_1.lenght - 1;` should be **length**

Comment: LMFAO! goes to show... one little thing. Of course works perfectly without the spelling error. Somwetimes it take another set of eyeballs to see stuff like that. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: It should really be `<script type="text/javascript">` because `language=`  is deprecated.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 and even then you should only need <script></script>

Comment: @BrentSmith Haha no problem. Glad that was the problem. I thought it might just be a minor fix. I added an answer nonetheless

Comment: Yeah i seen. Since it is the correct answer it was accepted as such. You should get credit where credit it due :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be a spelling error. Change the line:

```
totals = urls_1.lenght - 1;
```

to:

```
totals = urls_1.length - 1;
```

Also, the `language` attribute of `<script>` tags is deprecated, and instead you should use `type="text/javascript"`. If using the HTML5 doctype, the `type="text/javascript"` is assumed and isn't necessary to include.

Answer (score 0):

For alternating the two, you can try an algorithm like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) a.push(arr[i]);
        else b.push(arr[i]);
    }
```

Assuming `arr` is an array of all of the numbers and `n` is the length of `arr`. To convert the arrays to strings use `a.join(' ')` and set the HTML content accordingly.